# Price for literal vs int in Amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-cloudsearch

I'm designing search domain and here is my problem: I have a few columns, that don't need to be searchable, returnable or faceted. They have only a few possible values and will be used in fq parameter as filters.  The question is: which datatype to go with? Int or literal?

I'll get more maintainable solution with literal, because int would introduce an external dependency to other database/enum in my code. But will using literals increase the price? And how much? Couldn't find the answer in CS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon Cloudsearch's pricing model](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/pricing/) has the following components:

1. Instance hourly rate
2. Indexing cost based on the size of your data
3. Transfer rates

Your instance rates will depend on the amount of data you're storing. Essentially, every one of those models is directly or indirectly dependent on the size of the information you're storing.

Based on that, it would make sense to go with an integer field instead of a literal. A number is cheaper to store than it's literal equivalent. The difference might be negligible in the initial stages, but when you have a HUGE amount of information being indexed, it could be the difference between a small and medium instance and therefore save you some money.